# Javascript Animation From Scratch

Tags: javascript, animation

First of all: yes I do know that I want to reinvent the wheel. But this is not the point. I am new to Javascript (I had some basic training in school) and I want to understand not just copy and paste animations made in Javascript. I want to be able to chage certain parameters to make my web page look nicer.

So here is my problem (it is probably very stupid question but anyway). I found this Javascript Animation Tutorial: http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation#the-basics-of-the-animation

It is exactly what I was looking for, except that it is poorly writen (in my opinion (I am a perfectionist)) and somehow from time to time a bit harder to understand. So what I really do not get are lines 7 and 8 (Bold):

```
function animate(opts) {
    var start = new Date
    var id = setInterval(function () {
        var timePassed = new Date - start
        var progress = timePassed / opts.duration
        if (progress > 1) progress = 1
        var delta = opts.delta(progress)
        opts.step(delta)
        if (progress == 1) {
            clearInterval(id)
        }
    }, opts.delay || 10)
}
```

Everything else is understandable. And what I also do not get are Deltas (I understand mathematical concept and stuff) but I do not understand how to use them (the proper way to use them).

If anyone is kind enough, to correct this code and to explain me what I have to write in line 7 of the folowing code, if I want to have linear Delta, I would be really grateful. And I would also like to know the way how to properly call the function to animate (in this case function move()).

```
function move(element, delta, duration) {
    var to = 500
    animate({
        delay:10,
        duration:duration || 1000, // 1 sec by default
        delta:delta,
        step:function (delta) {
            element.style.left = to * delta + "px"
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Ok I finally got it. I still do not know what exactly was wrong, but I managed to get it working after rewriting everything very carefully. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the tutorial and it appears to me that delta is merely an attribute used to keep track of how far along the animation is in its motion. The number will always be between 0 and 1, so at the beginning of the animation the element.style.left = 0px and at the end it is equal to 500px.  Depending on your inputs, the value could be set to be linear or exponential (having easing).

Is your code not working right now? or are you just wondering about what the delta was?

Answer (score 0):

```
function move(element, delta, duration) {
    var to = 500
    animate({
        delay: 10,
        duration: duration || 1000, // 1 sec by default
        delta: delta,
        step: function(delta) {
            element.style.left = 100*delta + "px"    
        }
    }) 
}
```

On the page you mentioned, on the delta section, there is this mapping:

- progress = 0 -> height = 0%
- progress = 0.2 -> height = 20%
- progress = 0.5 -> height = 50%
- progress = 0.8 -> height = 80%
- progress = 1 -> height = 100%

And they define delta as:

> delta(progress) is the function which maps time progress "progress" to
>   animation progress "delta".

It means a linear delta should be a function which follow those rules:

- delta(0) -> "0%"
- delta(0.2) -> "20%"
- delta(0.4) -> "50%"
- delta(0.8) -> "80%"
- delta(1) -> "100%"

This is defined by the line: "delta: delta," on your example.

The step function will apply this delta to your code. In this case, you use:

```
element.style.left = to*delta + "px"
```

A delta of 0 means that attribute will be "0px". A delta of 1 means that attribute will be "500px".
A progress of 0 indicates the start of the animation and a progress of 1 indicates the end of the animation. In this example, the delta is equal to the progress.
In the middle of the animation, progress is 50%. Since delta(0.5) = 0.5, the argument passed to step will be 0.5 and the attribute will be "250px".

I advise you to use the developer console available on your to test the value of the attribute which you apply to the element.

Comment: What is really confusing me are the lines var delta = opts.delta(progress) and opts.step(delta). Could you please explain to me what do they do?

Comment: You are defining opts.delta and opts.step inside the function move. Check this: http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation#example1
"delta: delta" means function(p) { return p }. The step function is assigning that value to some element. I just realized that I missed you were using an absolute value for the element.style.left.